# Get coordinates of the points in an ellipse in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

In HTML5 Canvas, I know I can draw an ellipse with `CanvasRenderingContext2D.ellipse()`, but how can I draw some points on the ellipse path?

I can draw points on a circular path using the following codes:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('thumbCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const distance = 200;
const centerX = canvas.width / 2;
const centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var angle = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
  angleInRadian = angle * Math.PI / 180;
  ctx.fillRect(centerX - imgWidth / 2 + distance * Math.cos(angleInRadian), centerY - imgHeight / 2 + distance * Math.sin(angleInRadian), 5, 5);
  angle += 10;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

p.s. ignore the colors and the dot at the center.

But how to do this with an ellipse? I don't want to use `ctx.scale()` to distort the whole image.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22064/calculating-a-point-that-lies-on-an-ellipse-given-an-angle

Comment: that's embarrassing. My math is so bad that I can't even know how to apply the formula to JavaScript. Can you help me a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment your little rectangles are drawn along a perfect circle because the `distance` from the center is always the same. If you want to draw an oval, you have to vary the distance horizontally and vertically.

For example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('thumbCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const distanceX = 60;
const distanceY = 30;
const centerX = canvas.width / 2;
const centerY = canvas.height / 2;
let imgWidth = 10;
let imgHeight = 10;
var angle = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
  angleInRadian = angle * Math.PI / 180;
  ctx.fillRect(centerX - imgWidth / 2 + distanceX * Math.cos(angleInRadian), centerY - imgHeight / 2 + distanceY * Math.sin(angleInRadian), 5, 5);
  angle += 10;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="thumbCanvas"></canvas>
```